# How do I upgrade ReSharper 4.5 settings to ReSharper 5.0 settings

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, upgrade, resharper-4.5, resharper-5.0

I've recently upgraded my code from Visual Studio 2008 .NET 3.5 to Visual Studio 2010 .NET 4.0.

I've used ReSharper 4.5 and now I'm using ReSharper 5.0.

I want my ReSharper 4.5 settings (the ones in .resharper file) to be upgraded to ReSharper 5.0 settings.

Is there an automatic way to do it? Should I do it manually? Would just overwriting the .5.0.ReSharper file with the .4.5.resharper file do that trick?

Comment: If you figured a way, please let us know